# Is there anything I can use to mock an AD API for getting a list of users?

Tags: windows, active-directory, mocking, forms-authentication, authorization

I don't need AD for anything more than getting a list of user names. My application uses it's own, custom auth, but it does checks based on the domain username of the logged on user, so the user names in my Users table should match those used by the logged on users.

E.g. For domain user *johnblack* to access features in my app, the app admin must create a user in my app called johnblack, but when creating this user, the username is a free text field. This allows the app admin to mistakenly create a user called jonblack. I want to make the user name field a dropdown, populated with users from the domain, when the admin adds a new user.

However, the epic saga involved in getting AD running on a VM on my Win 7 Home laptop is just too much overhead for now. Are their any mocks I could use, where my C# code needn't change to switch over to real AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) - formerly also know as AD/AM (AD Application Mode).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa705886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It's a lightweight version of AD, which smells like AD, behaves like AD, but it's a NT service that you can start (and stop) at will, and it doesn't completely take over your machine/server - you can easily disable/uninstall it.

Comment: Yes and it exists a [LDS version for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14683)